# How is it possible to access a Python object using Pybind11 in a C callback?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a C++ DLL that embeds python interpreter using `Pybin11`. The Python side of the project accepts callbacks and passes some arguments to  them. The callbacks then are executed on the C++/C/C# etc part. On C++ side I can freely use `pybind11::object` can handle complex types such as OpenCV images (using `py::array_t` for example); however, when it comes to exposing it to  the C which can be then used for variety of languages including C#, I fail.

The reason I fail, is that I can't simply cast the `py::object` to a type that C understands and vice versa. for example, I can't simply change my C++ callback which is :

```cpp
typedef void(*CallbackFn)(bool, std::string, py::array_t<uint8_t>&);

void default_callback(bool status, std::string id, py::array_t<uint8_t>& img)
{
    auto rows = img.shape(0);
    auto cols = img.shape(1);
    auto type = CV_8UC3;
    cv::Mat img1(rows, cols, type, img.mutable_data());
   ...

}
```

to its C compatible variant :

```cpp
typedef void(*CallbackFn)(bool, char*, void*);
void default_callback(bool status, char* id, void* img)
{
    //cast the void* into something useful
    ...
}
```

This simply causes an exception on Python side which simply says,

```py
TypeError: (): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: bool, arg1: str, arg2: capsule) -> None

Invoked with: True, '5', array([[[195, 216, 239],
        [194, 215, 237],
        [193, 214, 236],
        ...,
        [ 98, 108, 143],
        [100, 110, 147],
        [101, 111, 149]]], dtype=uint8)
```

using other objects (for example on an opencv `img.data` I get errors such as this :

```py
TypeError: (): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: bool, arg1: str, arg2: capsule) -> None

Invoked with: True, '5', <memory at 0x0000021BC3433D68>
```

So my question is, how should I go about this, so that I don't get an exception on Python part? How can I access to an object pointer in Python? is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a `Pybind11` bug and creating an issue on Pybind11 didn't help, so I ended up using a delegate callback. That is use a middle callback for converting between the two format. I explained this in detail in my [previous (related) question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61224511/2736559).